# MakeRouteEventLayer_lr Vs Display Route Events

Tags: arcpy, python-script-tool, linear-referencing, workspace

I've two script tools. The first one prepares data for the second script to work. The first tool routes a table along a line using MakeRouteEventLayer_lr. The second script tool reads the selection made on the layer created by first tool.

First tool:

```
SMr = arcpy.MakeRouteEventLayer_lr(Route,"ID",dbf,"ID LINE Beg End","Lyr Events")

SMrLyr = SMr.getOutput(0)

SMlyr=arcpy.mapping.AddLayer(df,SMrLyr)
```

Second tool:

```
Route  = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0) # I point to the layer created from First tool

SMSelCount = int(arcpy.GetCount_management(Route).getOutput(0))
```

If I select few records in the layer from first tool then the second tool should count it for me but instead it gives me count of entire table.

Now if I use Display Route Event(by right clicking the table) and use the resulting layer for second tool then every thing works fine. The second tool can read any  selection made on the layer.

So I was wondering if there is any difference between these two ways of routing. I was under the impression that they are essentially the same thing. Could it be because of the workspace, one using "in-memory" vs other using default.gdb in C drive?

Comment: When you wired up your second script to it's interface, what was the data type of your parameter 0? It needs to be a FeatureLayer if you want it to honour selections.

Comment: I tried 'FeatureLayer' and 'Any value' but didn't work in either case. At the same time the resulting layer from 'Display Route events' seem to work in either type of parameter.

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured out a way. I read the explanation below for the Make Route Event Layer tool on the ESRI resources.

*"Not all types of tables have an ObjectID field. When such tables are used by this tool the resulting layer will not be selectable and cannot be used effectively by certain geoprocessing operations. Consider using theMake Query Table tool prior to this tool to add a virtual ObjectID field."*

My tables do have these ObjectID fields, but still the output was not selectable, and could not be used by my other geoprocessing tool. I instead ended up saving the resulting layer from the tool and adding it back to the map. Now the saved feature is selectable and I can use it in my other tool.

`SMr = arcpy.MakeRouteEventLayer_lr(Route,"ID",dbf,"ID LINE Beg End","Lyr Events")
SMrLyr = SMr.getOutput(0)
SMrLyrCopy = arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(SMrLyr,'LyrEventsSaved')
SMrLyrCopyOut = SMrLyrCopy.getOutput(0)
SMrLyrCopyOutDesc = arcpy.Describe(SMrLyrCopyOut)
SMrLyrCopyOutDescPath = SMrLyrCopyOutDesc.path
lyrPath = SMrLyrCopyOutDescPath + r'\\LyrEventsSaved'
SMRouted=arcpy.mapping.Layer(lyrPath)
arcpy.mapping.AddLayer(df,SMRouted,"TOP")`